# Yii: Displaying user data on the dynamic pie chart

Tags: php, yii

I am a yiibie. I have a view file which shows the top 5 user's of the year. I want to show the name of the users and percentage in the pie chart. For example, if it is the 1st top user then on the piechart it should appear 80% along with the username(maybe username upon hover) and if it's the 2nd top user then it should display the percentage less then 80% and so on for all the 5 users. 
This is the code for my controller

```
      public function actionAllstats()
{

    $this->layout='main';
    $myCurrYear = date("Y");
    $userYear=UserJoinEvent::model()->findAll(array(
        'condition' => 'YEAR(date_created)=:year',
        'params' => array(':year'=>$myCurrYear),
        'select'=>'user_id',
        'group'=>'user_id',
        'order'=>'COUNT(*) DESC',
        'limit' =>  5
     ));  
    $this->render('allstats', array("userYear"=>$userYear));
}
```

And this is the code for my view file

```
<div>   
    <?php // the for the year 
        foreach($userYear as $show) {
            $model = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$show->user_id,));
            if (isset($model)) {
                echo '<h3>' . $show->user_id .  ' - ' . $model->username . '</h3>';
            } 
             else {
                echo '<h3>' . $show->user_id .  ' - Username not found</h3>';
            } 
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

I tried to use the google pie chart but it didn't worked out. Please help me with this, thankyou

Comment: Have you considered some of the graphing libraries made from Bootstrap?

Comment: I have searched but dont know how to implement in my code and my project, can you please help me with this.

Comment: https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2 should help you get started but I'm not sure I know enough about what you're trying to accomplish to effectively answer this question